# MySQL CREATE and INSERT yields an unordered sequence of records when the table is populated

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, sql-insert, create-table

> Please, I acknowledge my #newbie state. Eery help is well appreciated.

So I created a table `n_s` as follows

```
CREATE TABLE n_s (
    state_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    state_name VARCHAR(50),
    state_capital VARCHAR(50),
    faac DECIMAL(16,2)
);
```

Then populated it like so

```
INSERT INTO n_s(state_name, state_capital, faac) VALUES ('Ab','Um',520),
('Ad','Yl',483),
('Akm','Uy',171);
```

At this point, I got a nice-looking table.

[image]

The problem then arises when I want to populate this table with new values. First, I did this:
`ALTER TABLE n_s ADD g_usd DECIMAL(30,2);`
and it worked fine. But then I tried populating the table with

```
INSERT INTO n_s(g_usd)  VALUES
(6073488295.68),
(5815471618.60),
(13267272645.16);
```

The result `SELECT * FROM n_s;` is the following "unordered " table:

[image: the ugly table]

However, what I really want to achieve using the above steps is:

[image: Expectation]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, finally.

I only had to replace

```
INSERT INTO n_s(g_usd)  VALUES
(6073488295.68),
(5815471618.60),
(13267272645.16);
```

with

```
INSERT INTO n_s(state_id, g_usd)  VALUES
(1, 6073488295.68),
(2, 5815471618.60),
(3, 13267272645.16) AS gs
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE g_usd = gs.g_usd;
```

And it works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `UPDATE` the existing rows, not `INSERT` new rows.

For example, you can do:

```
update n_s set g_usd = 6073488295.68 where state_id = 'Ab';
update n_s set g_usd = 5815471618.60 where state_id = 'Ad';
update n_s set g_usd = 13267272645.16 where state_id = 'Akm';
```

Comment: Thanks. Does it mean that if I have `100,000` rows, for example, I have to do it just this way? I had thought of the `update` method earlier but I did not use it because of the length of the table I am working on. Counting on your further suggestion.

Comment: @odunayo12 You can do it this way for 100k rows, of course, but it will be very, very tedious. Alternatively you can load the new data into a separate table (state_id, g_usd), and then use a single UPDATE that will update the primary table from the secondary one.

Comment: I found an answer. Your answer helped me with a clue which I used in searching Google. Thanks